# How can I execute this System.Linq statement faster?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have an enumerable of a custom class that I am taking a subset of, like this:

```
var sourceSet = await GetSourceSetData(inputParam1, inputParam2);

_logger.Info.Write(message: "CheckpointA");

var resultSet = sourceSet.Where(x => (x.Property1 + x.Property2 > 0) ||
                                     (!myBoolean && x.Property3.SubProperty > x.Property4));

_logger.Info.Write(message: "CheckpointB");
```

GetSourceData is made up of several db calls...

```
var dataTask1 = _db.GetThisData(inputList);
var dataTableForTVP = GetCutoffDates(inputList, myBoolean).CopyToDataTable();
var dataTask2 = _db.GetThatData(dataTableForTVP, myBoolean);
var dataTask3 = _db.GetMoreData(inputList, myBoolean);
var dataTask4 = _db.GetEvenMoreData(inputList);
var dataTask5 = _db.GetMoarMoreData(inputList);

var task1Result = await dataTask1;
var task2Result = await dataTask2;
var task3Result = await dataTask3;
var task4Result = await dataTask4;
var task5Result = await dataTask5;

var sourceSuperSet = inputList.Select(x => new MyCustomClass()
{
    IdProperty = x.IntProperty,
    CategoryProperty = 0,
    PropertyY = task1Result.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdProperty == x.IntProperty) == null ? 0.00m : task1Result.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdProperty == x.IntProperty).DecimalProperty,
    Property3 = task2Result.FirstOrDefault(z => z.IdProperty == x.IntProperty) ?? new FourPropertyClass() {IdProperty = x.IntProperty, DecProperty1 = 0, DecProperty2 = 0},
    PropertyU = task3Result.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdProperty == x.IntProperty) == null ? 0.00m : task3Result.FirstOrDefault(u => u.IdProperty == x.IntProperty).DecimalProperty,
    PropertyV = task4Result.FirstOrDefault(v => v.IdProperty == x.IntProperty) == null ? 0.00m : task4Result.FirstOrDefault(v => v.IdProperty == x.IntProperty).DecimalProperty,
    PropertyW = task5Result.FirstOrDefault(w => w.IdProperty == x.IntProperty) == null ? 0.00m : task5Result.FirstOrDefault(w => w.IdProperty == x.IntProperty).DecimalProperty
});

return sourceSuperSet.Where(x => x.Property3.DecPropertyCalc > 0 &&
                                (x.Property3.DecProprtyCalc - x.PropertyY > 0.0m || 
                                 x.PropertyW - x.PropertyV > 0.0m)
                           );
```

It's taking a really long time (like 12 minutes) to go from checkpoint A to checkpoint B for only a couple thousand items in the enumerable.  What would be a better way to get the result I'm looking for?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this talking to a database? Can you materialize it into a list before performing Linq operations on it?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought as well.  What type is `sourceSet`?

Comment: sourceSet is an IEnumerable<MyCustomClass>, so everything should already be in memory I think

Comment: Are your Property#s doing anything in the get{} part?

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question to show what statement is used to assign "data" to `sourceSet`. In other words: what is on the right hand side of `sourceSet = `? And If that assignment uses other sources, show those assignments as well. It also helps if we get to see the definition of `MyCustomClass`.

Comment: Also: a `DbSet<T>` can be used in every place where an `IEnumerable<T>` is needed, so having that interface does not say anything about the nature of the source.

Comment: @LarsTech yeah, Property2 is PropertyZ - PropertyY, which are both decimals.
  Property1 is PropertyX + PropertyW, which are both decimals.  
Property3.SubProperty is Property3.SubPropA + Property3.SubPropB.  
Property4 is a decimal.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the type.  Is the Property1 simply returning a value, or is there some calculation or something else going on.  There's not reason otherwise why your code would be acting slow.  While it's running, hit the "Break All" debugger and see where it's stopping.

Comment: @LarsTech yes, Property2 is a calculation.  That calculation is the difference of two decimal properties.  Property 1 is also a calculation, the sum of two decimal properties.  So yes, they are calculations, but of pretty basic arithmetic complexity.  Do you think this type of calculation could cause a slowdown like this?  Would it be better to make class methods to return these operations rather than properties?  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterB, I've updated the question with more detail, is that enough to help understand the scope of what I'm getting at?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @maccettura can this be re-opened?  I've provided the info that was asked for.  Thanks!

Comment: What are the types of `task1Result` and the other `task?Result`s, e.g. what does `GetThatData` return? If you put `ToList` on the return, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LINQ [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) method, to create lookups of the secondary data:

```
var task1Lookup = task1Result.ToLookup(x => x.IdProperty);
var task2Lookup = task2Result.ToLookup(x => x.IdProperty);
var task3Lookup = task3Result.ToLookup(x => x.IdProperty);
var task4Lookup = task4Result.ToLookup(x => x.IdProperty);
var task5Lookup = task5Result.ToLookup(x => x.IdProperty);

var sourceSuperSet = inputList.Select(x => new MyCustomClass()
{
    IdProperty = x.IntProperty,
    CategoryProperty = 0,
    PropertyY = (task1Lookup[x.IntProperty].FirstOrDefault()?.DecimalProperty).GetValueOrDefault(0.00m),
    Property3 = (task2Lookup[x.IntProperty].FirstOrDefault()?.DecimalProperty).GetValueOrDefault(0.00m),
    PropertyU = (task3Lookup[x.IntProperty].FirstOrDefault()?.DecimalProperty).GetValueOrDefault(0.00m),
    PropertyV = (task4Lookup[x.IntProperty].FirstOrDefault()?.DecimalProperty).GetValueOrDefault(0.00m),
    PropertyW = (task5Lookup[x.IntProperty].FirstOrDefault()?.DecimalProperty).GetValueOrDefault(0.00m),
});
```